# Dynamic grouping by specific attributes with sorting

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, group-by, comparator

My problem is solved by the below answer except sorting on grouped attributes.

[Dynamic grouping by specific attributes with Collection.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770177/dynamic-grouping-by-specific-attributes-with-collection-stream)

How can i retrieve list from values set in sorted order based on the attributes in ascending or descending order. One group attribute can be ascending while other can be descending.

I've created a GroupClass as parameter instead of string array.

```
    public class MyClass {
    public String title;
    public String type;
    public String module;

    public MyClass(String title, String type, String module) {
        this.type = type;
        this.title = title;
        this.module = module;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [title=" + title + ", type=" + type + ", module=" + module + "]";
    }

    private static Map<List<String>, List<MyClass>> groupListBy(List<MyClass> data, List<GroupClass> groupFieldList) {
        final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        List<MethodHandle> handles = groupFieldList.stream().map(groupField -> {
            try {
                return lookup.findGetter(MyClass.class, groupField.getFieldName(), String.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> handles.stream().map(handle -> {
            try {
                return (String) handle.invokeExact(d);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new MyClass("Title1", "TYPEA", "MB"));
        data.add(new MyClass("Title2", "TYPEA", "MB"));
        data.add(new MyClass("Title3", "TYPEA", "MC"));
        data.add(new MyClass("Title4", "TYPEB", "MA"));

        List<GroupClass> groupFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
        groupFieldList.add(new GroupClass("type","asc"));
        groupFieldList.add(new GroupClass("module","asc"));

        System.out.println(groupListBy(data, groupFieldList));
    }
}

    public class GroupClass {

    String name;
    String order;

    public GroupClass(String fieldName, String fieldOrder) {
        super();
        this.name = fieldName;
        this.order = fieldOrder;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.name = fieldName;
    }
    public String getFieldOrder() {
        return order;
    }
    public void setFieldOrder(String fieldOrder) {
        this.order = fieldOrder;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
[TYPEA, MC]=[MyClass [title=Title3, type=TYPEA, module=MC]], 
[TYPEA, MB]=[MyClass [title=Title1, type=TYPEA, module=MB], MyClass [title=Title2, type=TYPEA, module=MB]], 
[TYPEB, MA]=[MyClass [title=Title4, type=TYPEB, module=MA]]
}
```

Output which i am trying to achieve:

```
{
[TYPEB, MA]=[MyClass [title=Title4, type=TYPEB, module=MA]],
[TYPEA, MB]=[MyClass [title=Title1, type=TYPEA, module=MB], MyClass [title=Title2, type=TYPEA, module=MB]],
[TYPEA, MC]=[MyClass [title=Title3, type=TYPEA, module=MC]] 
}
```

The above output is sorted by "type" column in descending order and by "module" column in ascending order.

Comment: The code of the linked Q&A produces a `Map<List<String>, List<MyClass>>` what do you want to sort by which criteria?

Comment: If sorting is what you're looking forward to, try streaming the attained `Map` entries and sort them based on the `Comparator`(as a method argument) while you collect them back to a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: You can create two comparator one for `title`  and another for `module`, then use `chained comparator` by using those two comparator

Comment: In your example code, you’re initializing both `GroupClass` objects with `"asc"` which contradicts your description that you want to have the `"type"` column in descending order. When you fix that, [my solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57687961/2711488) all provide the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it

> 1. Using java-8

```
   Map<Object, List<MyClass>> sortedModuleList=
                data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k.module));
   System.out.println(sortedModuleList);
```

Code snippet below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class GroupByModule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass p1 = new MyClass("Title1","TYPEA","MB");
        MyClass p2 = new MyClass("Title2","TYPEA","MB");
        MyClass p3 = new MyClass("Title3","TYPEA","MC");
        MyClass p4 = new MyClass("Title4","TYPEB","MA");

        List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p3);
        list.add(p4);

        Map<Object, List<MyClass>> sortedModuleList =
                list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k.module));
        System.out.println(sortedModuleList);
        }
    }


class MyClass {
        public String title;
        public String type;
        public String module;

        public MyClass(String string, String string2, String string3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
               this.type = type;
               this.title = title;
               this.module = module;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyClass [title=" + title + ", type=" + type + ", module=" + module + "]";
        }
}
```

Output :

```
{ 
   MA=[MyClass [title=Title4, type=TYPEB, module=MA]], 
   MB=[MyClass [title=Title1, type=TYPEA, module=MB], MyClass [title=Title2, type=TYPEA, module=MB]], 
   MC=[MyClass [title=Title3, type=TYPEA, module=MC]] 
}
```

---

> 2. Using ChainedComparator

Imagine if we don't having a `java8` `stream` feature, then we need to do go with like this. This is a bit old way of coding:

1. Lets create a bean MyClass

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {

    public String title;
    public String type;
    public String module;

    public MyClass(String title, String type, String module) {
        this.type = type;
        this.title = title;
        this.module = module;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [title=" + title + ", type=" + type + ", module=" + module + "]";
    }
 //getter and setter
}
```

2. Find how many fields you needs to sort , in this case `Type` first then `Module`. We need to create a two comparator one for `Type` and one for `Module`.

**TypeComparator.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class TypeComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2) {

         return obj1.getType().compareTo(obj2.getType());
    }
}
```

**Modulecomparator.java**

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Modulecomparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2) {

         return obj1.getModule().compareTo(obj2.getModule());
    }
}
```

3. Now we need to write one `ChainedComparator` where it acts as a bridge between `TypeComparator` and `ModuleComparator`.

**MyClassChainedComparator.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
public class MyClassChainedComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {

     private List<Comparator<MyClass>> listComparators;


     public MyClassChainedComparator(Comparator<MyClass>... comparators) {
         this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
     }

     @Override
     public int compare(MyClass myclass1, MyClass myclass2) {
         for (Comparator<MyClass> comparator : listComparators) {
             int result = comparator.compare(myclass1, myclass2);
             if (result != 0) {
                 return result;
             }
         }
         return 0;
     }
}
```

4. Do a `sort` by chaining between `TypeComparator` and `ModuleComparator` with the help of `MyClassChainedComparator` like this :

**MyClassResult.java**

```
public class MyClassResult {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add( new MyClass("Title1", "TYPEA", "MB") );
        list.add( new MyClass("Title2", "TYPEA", "MB") );
        list.add( new MyClass("Title3", "TYPEA", "MC") );
        list.add(new MyClass("Title4", "TYPEB", "MA") );

        Collections.sort(list,new MyClassChainedComparator(new Modulecomparator(),new TypeComparator()));

        for(MyClass myc:list){
            System.out.println(myc);
        }
}
}
```

Output :

```
MyClass [title=Title4, type=TYPEB, module=MA]
MyClass [title=Title1, type=TYPEA, module=MB]
MyClass [title=Title2, type=TYPEA, module=MB]
MyClass [title=Title3, type=TYPEA, module=MC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way, your groups are determined, is irrelevant to the task of of sorting them. At the end of your process, you have a `Map<List<String>, List<MyClass>>` with the `List<String>` keys containing all necessary information.

So the task boils down to sorting `List<String>` values. This can be done by composing comparators comparing the individual elements.

```
Comparator<List<String>> comp = IntStream.range(0, groupFieldList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> {
        Comparator<List<String>> c = Comparator.comparing(l -> l.get(i));
         // you should better use a boolean or enum for the direction
        if(!groupFieldList.get(i).getFieldOrder().equals("asc"))
            c = c.reversed();
        return c;
    })
    .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing).orElse((a,b) -> 0);
```

Then, there are two options. The first is to use the comparator to collect into a sorted map:

```
return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    d -> handles.stream().map(handle -> {
        try {
            return (String) handle.invokeExact(d);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()),
    () -> new TreeMap<>(comp),
    Collectors.toList()));
```

The second is to collect into a map as before, followed by another stream operation sorting the elements and collecting into a map that retains the insertion order:

```
return data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> handles.stream().map(handle -> {
        try {
            return (String) handle.invokeExact(d);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(comp))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b)->{throw new AssertionError();}, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Since we’re sorting by the key rather than a computed group value, we can replace the first grouping with a plain mapping to an entry holding key and (not yet aggregated) value and collect the group values in the second operation:

```
return data.stream()
    .map(d -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(handles.stream().map(handle -> {
        try {
            return (String) handle.invokeExact(d);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()), d))
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(comp))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```