# Dynamic Grouping using groupby() in java

Tags: java, collections, group-by, java-stream, collectors

I am working on some scenario.

where the user selects some columns and the grouping on them is done and displayed.

I have done using criteria and now I want to use java **groupby()**  to group.

Consider I have an entity Employee:

```
package com.demo;

public class Employee {
    
    int id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String phoneno;
    String designation;
    
    
    public Employee(int id, String name, String address, String phoneno, String designation) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.designation = designation;
    }
}

// getter and setters
```

I have created another class for grouping

```
public class GroupHere {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {

Function<Employee, List<Object>> classifier = (emp) ->
        Arrays.<Object>asList(emp.getAddress(),emp.getName());

Map<Employee, Long> groupedEmployee = employee.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println("key" + groupedEmployee .keySet());
System.out.println("Grouped by" + groupedEmployee );

   }
}
```

Now I wanted to dynamically create my classifier so when the user selects '''name''' and  '''phoneno'''
the classifier should have these getters in it.

I am confused here.

Also when user selects the attributes/column that details is in JSON.

```
{
 [ attributes: name, groupable: true ],
 [ attributes: phoneno, groupable: true ]
}
```

How can I map the *attributes* with the *getters* of **Employee** and add into *classifier* ?

Or is their any other way to group this attributes?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770177/dynamic-grouping-by-specific-attributes-with-collection-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by using a map from attribute names to attribute extractors, i.e:

```
Map<String, Function<Employee, Object>> extractors = new HashMap<>();
extractors.put("name", Employee::getName);
extractors.put("address", Employee::getAddress);
extractors.put("phoneno", Employee::getPhoneno);
extractors.put("designation", Employee::getDesignation);
```

Once you have this map, you can use it to create your classifier dynamically:

```
List<String> attributes = ...; // get attributes from JSON (left as exercise)

Function<Employee, List<Object>> classifier = emp -> attributes.stream()
    .map(attr -> extractors.get(attr).apply(emp))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, you can use this classifier to gruop the employees:

```
Map<List<Object>, Long> groupedEmployees = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.counting()));
```